# Module not found error with monorepo peer deps

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, turborepo, peer-dependencies

We are building a monorepo project with TurboRepo and yarn 3 workspaces. In our monorepo we have two packages `website` and `core`.`website` is a nextjs application and `core` is a reusable component library bundled with rollup. We have the following package.json declarations in both of these projects:

```
// website package.json
...
 "dependencies": {
   "core": "*",
   "next-auth": "^4.22.1"
   ....
}
...
```

and

```
// core package.json
...
 "peerDependencies": {
   "next-auth": "4.x",
   ....
}
...
```

So `website` has a dependencies to `next-auth` and `core` and this last one has a peer dependency to `next-auth`. When building the `website` project we get the following error:

```
 website:build: ../../core/dist/index.js
 website:build: Module not found: Can't resolve 'next-auth/react'
```

If website has `next-auth` in its dependencies why is this error happening?